# Error while using web version of Gurobi solver

Tags: gurobi

I am trying to solve a linear programming problem using the Gurobi solver web version. This is the link: http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html 
But irrespective of the problem I submit, I get the following error:

> ---------- Begin Solver Output -----------
>   Executing /opt/neos/Drivers/gurobi/gurobi-mps-wrapper-driver.py at time: 2013-06-10 14:17:48.434197
>   Error: /usr/bin/env: /opt/gurobi/latest/linux64/bin/python2.5: No such file or directory

I am submitting files in the MPS format.

Why am I getting this error?